# Would having the call stack grow upward make buffer overruns safer?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, intel, buffer-overflow

Each thread has its own stack to store local variables. But stacks are also used to [store return addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) when calling a function.

In x86 assembly, `esp` points to the most-recently allocated end of the stack.  Today, most CPUs have stack grow negatively. This behavior enables arbitrary code execution by overflowing the buffer and overwriting the saved return address. If the stack was to grow positively, such attacks would not be feasible.

Is it safer to have the call stack grow upwards?  Why did Intel design 8086 with the stack growing downward?  Could they have changed things in any later CPUs to let modern x86 have stacks that grow upwards?

Comment: Maybe your question fits better in [Security StackExchange.](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RyanB I don't think so. The question is why the stack is growing downards *despite* the security issue (one that didn't really "exist" back when x86 was designed).

Comment: Given that the 8086 was just born as a humble microcontroller, I doubt anyone considered the security implications of a down-growing stack against untrusted data coming from malicious users on a worldwide network. ;-)

Comment: Emma don't modern Intel chips also have this downward growing stack model? Why change this question to 8086 specific? @Peter Cordes

Comment: @KelvinZhang: Modern x86 inherits that from 8086.  They couldn't have changed it between 8086 and 80186, or between 80186 and 80286, or ...  **8086 is when this design decision was set in stone**.  But good point, I reworded the last sentence, thanks for pointing out that it didn't sound quite like you intended.

Comment: I fail to see how up or down makes a difference you can overflow either way.

Comment: If the stack grows upward, you won't be able to overwrite return address no matter how hard you try. (Since return address is saved before the execution of current function.) @dwelch

Comment: @dwelch past-the-end is a lot more common.  Security precautions don't have to be foolproof to be useful.

Comment: You don't have to have downward growing stacks in the x86.  Don;t confuse the presence of a feature for the necessity of using it. Just stay away from push/pop/call and use another register to implement upward-growing stacks.   I doubt there would even be much a performance penalty.

Comment: @KelvinZhang It's possible to "underflow" a buffer on the stack as well. Consider `strcpy(stack_buf + input.header_len, input.data)` which can overwrite the values on the the stack before `stack_buf` if `header_len` is so large it wraps around.

Comment: You would have to start the stack much much lower than making it much easier to overflow into.  as the stack unwinds you still run into the collision.  up vs down is not relevant.

Comment: @IraBaxter: A manual implementation of `ret` can't take advantage of the return-address predictor.  You could use a RIP-relative LEA and a JMP to emulate branch-with-link without much perf penalty, but I think the indirect JMP to emulate RET is where this might bite you.  Or were you picturing a dual-stack setup where you separate automatic-storage allocation from the call stack?

Comment: @dwelch: if your stack grows upward, you'd reverse the usual memory layout, and put code / static data / heap at the top, and the stack at the bottom.  So **the heap would grow downward while the stack grows upward**, and you have the same amount of room before they meet in the middle.  Or else you have a 64-bit address space and plenty of room for an upward-growing stack and heap.  (The stack can be (and is on Linux) outside the low 2GiB of address space).

Comment: @PeterCordes: yeah the shadow stack predictor wouldn't work, and that would have a noticeable affect on performance. I just wanted to make the case that you can program the machine without using the built-ins if you insist. Regarding call-stack allocation: our PARLANSE language in fact does heap allocation of activation records. We do use the CALL instruction to push the return address on the stack (local to the current activation record); the callee allocates a new activation record and sets ESP to point someplace convenient inside that. Penalty: about 3%. Payoff: unlimited recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting point; most buffer overruns do go past the end, not before the beginning, so this would almost certainly help.  Compilers could put local arrays at the highest address in a stack frame, so there wouldn't be any scalar locals to overwrite located after an array.

There's still danger if you pass the address of a local array to another function, though.  Because the return address of the called function would be located just past the end of the array.

```
unsafe() {
    char buf[128];
    gets(buf);      // stack grows upward: exploit happens when gets executes `ret`
    // stack grows down: exploit happens when the `ret` at the end of *this* function executes.
}
```

**So probably a *lot* of buffer overruns will still be possible**.  This idea only defeats buffer overruns when the unsafe array-writing code is inlined, so the overrun happens with nothing important above the array.

However, some other common causes of buffer overruns can easily be inlined, like `strcat`.  **Upward growing stacks will help sometimes.**

Security measures don't have to be foolproof to be useful, so this would definitely help sometimes.  Probably not enough for anyone to want to change an existing architecture like x86, but **an interesting idea for new architectures**.  Stack-grows-down is a nearly universal standard in CPUs, though.  Does anything use an upward-growing call stack?  How much software actually depends on that assumption?  Hopefully not much...

---

**The traditional layout left room for the heap and/or the stack to grow, only causing a problem if they meet in the middle.**

Predictable code/data addresses are more important than predictable stack addresses, so a computer with more RAM could put the stack farther from data/code, while still loading code/data at a constant address.  (This is very hand-wavy.  I consider myself lucky not to have written actual 16-bit programs, and only learned about but not used segmentation.  Perhaps someone that still remembers DOS can shed some light here on why it works well to have the stack at a high address, instead of an upward-growing stack at the bottom of your segment and data/code at the top.  e.g. with a "tiny" code model where everything is in one segment).

---

**The only real chance to change this behaviour was with AMD64**, which is the first time x86 has ever really broken backwards compatibility.  Modern Intel CPUs still support 8086 undocumented opcodes like [`D6`: `SALC` (Set AL from Carry Flag)](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html), limiting the coding space for ISA extensions.  (e.g. [SSSE3 and SSE4 instructions would be 1 byte shorter](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25) if Intel dropped support for undocumented opcodes.

Even then, it would only be for the new mode; AMD64 CPUs still have to support legacy mode, and when in 64-bit mode they have to mix long mode with compat mode (usually to run 32-bit user-space processes from 32-bit binaries).

AMD64 could maybe have added a stack-direction flag, but that would have made the hardware more complex.  As I argued above, I don't think it would have been a big benefit for security.  Otherwise, perhaps AMD architects would have considered it, but still unlikely.  They were definitely aiming for minimally intrusive, and weren't sure it would catch on.  They didn't want to be stuck with extra baggage to maintain AMD64 compatibility in their CPUs if the world mostly just kept running 32-bit OSes and 32-bit code.

That's a shame, because there are a lot of minor things they could have done that would probably not have required too many extra transistors in the execution units.  (e.g. in long mode, replace `setcc r/m8` with `setcc r/m32`).

Comment: If the stack grows positively from the very beginning, would it be better?

Comment: Also...If the `gets` call is inlined, there would not be security issues.

Comment: @KelvinZhang: you mean if 8086 had had upward-growing stacks?  That wouldn't change anything for the first part of my answer, showing that typical C is still vulnerable.  The middle part of my answer proposes a theory about why downward-growing stacks were common, especially before virtual memory.

Comment: `gets` is a library function.  It never gets inlined on normal systems, which is why I chose it for this example, instead of `strcat`.  However, I did update my answer to mention that `strcat` may inline.

Comment: Update: yes, stack growing upward from the bottom, heap growing *downward* from the top, could be equivalent.  It makes `realloc` to grow the last allocation harder (you have to copy since the start is at a different place after growing), but no different if there was an intervening allocation.