# How memory is allocated for a static array on the stack?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, gdb, stack-frame

I started a deep study of exploits, working with memory, etc., and ran into the same problem. Everywhere it is written that memory is allocated to variables in the order of their declaration inside the function, but in my case it has absolutely no effect on this, i.e. the pointer to the first element of the array in any of the options remains in one place.
Here is an example: I have a code in C

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    void myFunction() {
        char x[20];
        int a =1;
        int b= 2;
        int c = 3;
        int d = 4;
    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        myFunction();
    }
```

I compile it and debug it, and output the value of the address of the array x:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og4tC.png)
Then I edit the code and declare the array after initializing the d variable:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  void myFunction() {
     int a =1;`your text`
     int b= 2;
     int c = 3;
     int d = 4;
     char x[20];
  }
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     myFunction();
  }
```

And I do the same operations as in the previous case:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0jXp.png)

As you can see, the position of the array on the stack has not changed in any way, can you please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: None of your arrays are `static`.  Also, don't post pictures of text.  Especially not at 2 different zoom levels so we can't even flip back and forth to see what's different.  Also, your code blocks have stray `your text` in them so wouldn't compile.

Comment: GDB disables ASLR by default, so stack addresses will be the same across two runs.  Also, if `-fstack-protector-strong` is enabled, it puts arrays at the highest addresses of stack frames, above scalars, so buffer overflows can only overwrite the stack cookie, not other local vars.

Comment: "Everywhere it is written that memory is allocated to variables in the order of their declaration inside the function" Everywhere is wrong then, where did you read that?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as text.

Comment: I would suggest starting to learn how to format the code, before you start to learn how to become a hacker/cracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How memory is allocated for a static array on the stack?

None of the objects defined in your program are static. They all have automatic storage duration, not static. Static objects are not stored on the stack.

> Everywhere it is written that memory is allocated to variables in the order of their declaration inside the function,…

This is not written everywhere, and it is not true generally. Any source that says that is wrong. It might be partially true in some limited circumstances, such as compiling without optimization, but it is not true generally.

> As you can see, the position of the array on the stack has not changed in any way, can you please explain to me why this is happening?

Compilers commonly group objects by their alignment requirements (among other factors), to reduce the total amount of space needed for them. In this case, the compiler has put all of the `int` objects, which likely have a four-byte alignment requirement, first<sup>1</sup>, and has put the `char` array, which has a one-byte alignment requirement, after them. That choice of location remained the same regardless of the order in which the definitions appear.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This does not mean first in chronological order. In this case, the compiler seems to be organizing more-strictly-aligned objects at lower addresses, hence first in address order, not first in the direction the stack is grown. Other design choices could be made, such as putting the more strictly aligned objects at higher addresses.

Comment: `char x[20];` has a size >= 16 bytes, so GCC will actually align it by 16.  (The x86-64 System V ABI even specifies this, yes even for arrays in automatic storage, which is weird because it's not actually at an ABI boundary.)  Its size is a multiple of 4 so it could mix with `int` objects just fine if it wasn't for that alignment requirement, e.g. if it was 12 bytes, but yeah separating by `alignof()` is one way to group things.

Comment: Another relevant effect is that `-fstack-protector-strong` puts arrays at the top of a stack frame, just below the stack cookie, so scalars can't be overwritten by buffer overflows.  On many Linux distros, this is on my default.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Note to anybody making a new ABI: Make stacks grow toward higher addresses, so buffer overruns cannot affect the return address, saved frame pointer, and higher stack frames.

Comment: That's not as helpful as you'd think at first glance.  [Would having the call stack grow upward make buffer overruns safer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39187276) points out that `strcpy(buffer, too_long)` could overwrite `strcpy`'s return address instead of the caller's if you had stacks grow upward.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Okay, new plan: Upon calling any function, we start its stack frame in a new random location, with plenty of unmapped pages (in the huge virtual address space) between the frames.

Comment: That sounds bad for performance, such as dTLB entries, but even moreso actually mapping and unmapping those pages, unless you randomize once so repeated calls (e.g. printf in a loop) can use the same page.  In a multi-threaded program, unmapping a page normally requires TLB shootdowns to invalidate it for all other threads.  But if you're designing an ABI around this, maybe you can have OS support to keep unmapping priavte to that thread for callees you can prove didn't pass pointers to their locals to any other threads?  But if it's the caller doing the unmapping, they can't assume...